# Russell v. Meinong

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, ontology, contemporary-philosophy

Was the crux/essence of Russell's quarrel with Meinong a matter of epistemology or ontology?  As I recall, it had primarily to do with fictive objects/non-denoting expressions, and Russell's theory of [definite] descriptions.  But do not recall the specifics, or the extent to which Quinian pragmatic ontology/ontological commitment put it to rest.  If so, what is, has given rise to, Neomeinnongism (a term I recently ran into for the first time)?

Comment: It's a matter of both. Zalta's [comprehension principle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/existence/#Mei) may have contributed to recent Neomeinnongism...

Answer (score 1):

It's primarily ontological. Meinong's innovation was how to think about such things as unicorns. They do not exist but yet we can reason about them. His theory of dealing with this grew out of his work on intention and that we can intend impossibilia, that is impossible objects.

Whatever is the target of a thought, he called an object. He then distinguished the being of an object where it can be the target of a thought from its actual existence which refers to its substantative ontological existence which it may or may not have - both horses and unicorns have being in his theory but only horses have existence.

Meinong called objects without existence homeless. Other theorists say they live in Meinong's Jungle due to its great complexity and exoticism.

(However, there is a place in Meinong's Jungle which is quite nice. This is where classical logic applies: so here one unicorn plus one unicorn makes gor two unicorns. I am going to Christen this, pace anyone telling me that this notion has already been named, as Meinong's Clearing or Oasis. I prefer the latter term. Of course you don't get oasises in jungles but this is Meinong's Jungle where exotic things happen).

Russell thought highly of Meinong's work and until formulating his theory of descriptions held similar views. Whilst Chisholm and Parsons have demonstrated the consistency of Meinong's theory.

Russell in his essay, *On Denoting*, published in 1905, chiefly objects to Meinong's theory because he objects to such objects as:

> round square object

Meinong replied that ordinary classical logic does not apply to non-existent objects: A round square object is not round AND square. Instead, it is BOTH square round. The entire predicate must apply and not any constituent parts.

Although some people have suggested that Meinong thought existence as a property so rendering ontology into epistemology. A close reading, according to Wikipedia, shows that he do not think so. His objects are beyond existence and non-existence and lie in (his) Being (that is,his Jungle). According to him, essence is exemplified by properties.

Personally, I prefer his theory to Quinean Possible Worlds.